# for loop initializer is not working

Tags: c, visual-studio

I am doing the program below in visual studio.

```
// practice1.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "conio.h"
void addition();
void display(int a[][10],int row, int column);
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])

{
    addition();
    getch();
    return 0;
}
void addition()
{
    int a[10][10],b[10][10],m,n,k=0,j;
    printf("Enter order of matrix\n");
    //scanf("%d%d",&m,&n);
    m=2;n=3;
    printf("Enter matrix elements of matrix A\n");
    for(k=1;k<m;k++);
    {
        for(j=0;j<n;j++)
        {
            scanf("%d",&a[k][j]);
        }
    }
    printf("Enter matrix elements of matrix B\n");
    for(k=0;k<m;k++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<n;j++)
        {
            scanf("%d",&b[k][j]);
        }
    }
    //display(a,m,n);
    printf("\n");
    //display(b,m,n);
}




//void display(int a[][10],int row, int column)
//{
//  int i,j;
//  for(i=0;i<row;i++)
//  {
//      for(j=0;j<column;j++)
//      {
//          printf("%d",a[i][j]);
//      }
//      printf("\n");
//  }
//}
```

In First for loop, value of k is automatically set to 2 when control enters loop.
image attached. -

[image: Please note the value of k in watch window]

Comment: You are *not* debugging code compiled with optimization on, are you?

Comment: `for(k=1;k<m;k++);` remove `;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a typo on the line where the breakpoint is set.

The value is 2 because you have already exited the loop.

Remove the semicolon and try again.